# How to stop event propagation from within an anchor's href attribute without using onclick or onmousedown

Tags: javascript, jquery, anchor, event-propagation

Due to restrictions, even though it is something i avoid altogether, in a certain situation i have to use the javascript: syntax in a href attribute of an achor tag.

*(EXPLANATION: In my CMS i use a rich text editor to allow the user to make changes to text elements, including links. In some cases specific javascript: calls are required and i banned onclick completely from the link editing features (to simplify the process for the user). However, as one of the links appears within a block that reacts to an onclick event, the thing double-fires)*

Like this:

```
<a href="javascript:doSomething()"></a>
```

My problem is that this link is inside a container that already reacts to an onclick event. Therefore i wanted to pass the event object along to the doSomething() method, so that i could then use jQuery's

```
event.stopPropagation()
```

method.

Unfortunately however, it seems that passing the event object along

```
<a href="javascript:doSomething(event)"></a>
```

does not seem to work at all. Safari won't say anything while Firefox will report *ReferenceError: event is not defined*

I assume that this is the case because href="" is not a script-initiating attribute (such as onclick). The problem is that in this situation i won't be able to access the  tag beyond what i already do.

Therefore i either need

1.) A way to pass the event object to the doSomething() function from within the href attribute

or

2.) A way to stop the event propagation right in that anchor (after its clicked) by other means.

Thank You for any constructive input!

Comment: Why not just use jQuery to attach `doSomething` to the `click` event handler?

Comment: The situation requires it to be handled purely by what is possible using the href attribute.

Comment: If you could share why you must use the href attribute it may suggest possible work arounds.

Comment: You're right. I'll edit the question.

Comment: Change your <a> tags with href attributes to <span> tags with onclick attributes and your problem will be fixed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot stop event propagation from the `href` attribute because:

1. When the `href` code executes, it is not an event.  It just executes that code, similar to the "location hack".  Like entering `javascript:doSomething()` in the browser's address bar.
2. The href code executes ***after*** the events fire on the link -- including bubbling.

   You can see that behavior in [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QE8zt/1/).  Note that `mouseup`, `mousedown`, and `click` all fire both for the link, and on the container when the link is clicked, before the `href` code executes.

If there are event listeners that you want to block, you'll have to find another way.

---

But, **if you can append javascript to the document** you can block the `href` using `preventDefault()`.

For example:

- **jQuery, before version 1.7:**

  ```
  $("#container a").bind ("mousedown mouseup click", function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
  } );
  ```
- **jQuery 1.7 and later:**

  ```
  $("#container a").on ("mousedown mouseup click", function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
  } );
  ```

  or (better):

  ```
  $("#container").on ("mousedown mouseup click", "a", function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
  } );
  ```

You can [**see this last version live at jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/n7oo9o6d/).

Comment: Thank you so much for this! I was just having the same problem. Turning all of my <a> tags to <span> tags with onclicks solved the problem! Thanks again!

Comment: @SgtPooki, you are correct but please read the question and its comments.  The OP specifically states:
`"The situation requires it to be handled purely by what is possible using the href attribute."`.
But since the post-jQuery method might help others, I've added it to this answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot alter the link itself (to use onclick) then your only option is to alter the onclick handler of the container.

Can you do something like

```
function containerClickHandler(e) {
  e = e || event;
  var el = e.target || e.srcElement;
  if (el.nodeName === 'A' && someOtherMatchChecks) {
       // eat event
  }
  else {
       // process event
  }
}
```

Comment: That would be an option but i cannot do it because i would have to adapt some core code from my CMS only so that it suits a single case. But your approach is perfectly valid. Upvote.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is an old question, but in my particular case I did find a hack around it, but it might only apply to a subset of situations. I have a div that has an onclick. But if an  inside that div is clicked, I don't want that div's onclick to fire. Here is what I do:

```
function myOnClick () {

  // loop over all <a>'s, and test if they are hovered over right now.
  var allLinks = document.links;
  var dont = 0;
  for (var i = 0, n = allLinks.length; i < n; i++) {
    // pure javascript test to see if element is hovered.
    if(allLinks[i].parentElement.querySelector(":hover") === allLinks[i]) {dont = 1; }
  };

  if(dont)return;

  // your stuff here, only fires when dont is false.

}
```

I learned about the queryselector trick here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14800287/2295722

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a way to get the arguments if you write your javascript in href attribute. But you can get it as following in onclick, but as you say this isn't the best practice:

```
<a onclick="console.log(arguments)">your link</a>
```

in arguments array you'll get your event object.

here is a demo for you:

http://jsfiddle.net/tEw5J/1/

Comment: Thank You, but i cannot use onclick. Unfortunately.