# Detect if the mouse is over an element

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I get a pretty simple true/false-statement if the mouse is over a div event = true else event = false

```
  var test = $("#main-nav").on("mouseenter", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(e.preventDefault());
    return true;
});

if (test === true) {
   //do something
} else {
   //something different
}
```

Comment: Do you want this constantly updating as the user moves the mouse around, or do you need to know once "Is the mouse currently over element `#main-nav`".

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/on/

use it like $(document).on('mouseenter', '#main-nav', function(){...});

Comment: Answer for vanilla JS https://stackoverflow.com/a/46972433/1205871

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly:

```
if($("#main-nav").is(":hover")) {
   //do something
}else{
   //something different
}
```

In pseudo code:

```
if the cursor is over #main-nav
    do something
if it's not
    do something else
```

---

If you want `test` to always be set:

```
var test = false;
$("#main-nav").on("mouseenter", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    test = true;
}).on("mouseleave", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    test = false;
});
```

This way,

```
if(test === true) {
   //do something
}else{
   //something different
}
```

will *always* work.

Comment: Great answer, Maybe add a section in case OP wants to know how they could have gone about it using their original idea.

Comment: @minseong Can you explain what you mean by "gone about it using their original idea."? Thanks.

Comment: How could you check where the mouse is using mouseenter and leave?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a boolean (`true`/`false`) variable that will constantly update by doing this:

```
var hovering;
$("#main-nav").mouseenter(function(){
    hovering = true;
});
$("#main-nav").mouseleave(function(){
    hovering = false;
});
```

So whenever it is called it will tell you if the mouse is within your div:

```
if (hovering){
    // mouse within div
} else {
    // mouse not within div
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you necessarily need is as a variable:

```
var test = false;
$("#main-nav").on("mouseenter", function (e) {
    test = true;
});
$("#main-nav").on("mouseout", function (e) {
    test = false;
}); 

//....

if (test === true) {
   //do something
} else {
   //something different
}
```