# Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo: hover on IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer-8, fullcalendar

I'm using a fullcalendar library and I wanted my popover stay open on hover.

Here is the code I have that works as expected on Chrome.

```
            element.popover({
                html: true,
                animation: false,
                title: "Event",
                content: html_content,
                placement: "bottom",
                trigger: "manual"
            }).on("mouseenter", function() {
                var _this = this;
                $(this).popover("show");
                $(".popover").on("mouseleave", function() {
                    $(_this).popover('hide');
                });
            }).on("mouseleave", function() {
                var _this = this;
                setTimeout(function() {
                    if ($(".popover:hover").length === 0) {
                        $(_this).popover("hide");
                    }
                }, 100);
            });
```

The console error I get on IE8 is

> Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo: hover

Any help with this would be very much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: you cannot use the ":hover" pseudo-selector with IE8, that's it...

Comment: BTW which version of jQuery are you using ?

Comment: @n00dl3 1.9 so what's the work around for this? Can you provide me an example please?

Comment: Check out this answer, specifically the answer from user zb: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14795099/pure-javascript-to-check-if-something-has-hover-without-setting-on-mouseover-ou