# Find out if an element has a CSS "hover" pseudo-class defined?

Tags: javascript, html, css, pseudo-class

Let's say I have the following HTML:

```
<div id="mydiv">Hello</div>

<style>
#mydiv {
    background-color: yellow;
}

#mydiv:hover {
    background-color: red;
}
</style>
```

Using JavaScript, how would I determine whether #mydiv has the "hover" pseudo-class rule applied to it?

Ideally, it would be a function like the following:

```
function HasHoverPseudoClass(element){
    //if element has the "hover" pseudo-class then
    //return true
    //else
    //return false
}
```

Comment: You can try with html event attributes onmouseover and onmouseout

Comment: this might help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14795099/pure-javascript-to-check-if-something-has-hover-without-setting-on-mouseover-ou

Comment: I believe @sdn404 's answer is more directly related to the question than the duplicate post LGSon provided.

Comment: @MichaelSorensen So I added that link as well to the dupe list

Comment: Based on a few comments, are you asking how to check if the `#mydiv` is actually hovered, or whether it has a pseudo class assigned to it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Event `mouseover`**:

**With JS:**

```
var div = document.getElementById("mydiv");

div.addEventListener("mouseover", HasHoverPseudoClass);

    function HasHoverPseudoClass(){
        //if element has the "hover" pseudo-class then
        //return true
        //else
        //return false
    }
```

**With JQuery:**

```
$("#mydiv").mouseover(HasHoverPseudoClass);

function HasHoverPseudoClass(){
            //if element has the "hover" pseudo-class then
            //return true
            //else
            //return false
        }
```

I hope it's helps ;)

Comment: OP doesn't ask how to do "hover" with script, they ask if a given element have the "hover" class set in the CSS

Comment: He asks: "Using JavaScript, how would I determine whether #mydiv has the "hover" pseudo-class rule applied to it?" And my answer is If you run the mouseover event with an alert(for example), he can see if the :hover is active, since it is the same, right?

Comment: You might be correct with that interpretation, so I asked the  OP and will await their answer

Comment: And btw, the title, which I based my actions on, says _"Find out if an element has a CSS “hover” pseudo-class **defined**?"_