# How to detect if a certain tag is being hovered over

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code below from another post. It sends a message to the console everytime a certain element with an **id** was hovered over or not. How would I be able to do the same except it sends a message to the console everytime a certain **tag** was hovered over.

```
function isHover(e) {
 return (e.parentElement.querySelector(':hover') === e);
}


var myDiv = document.getElementById('mydiv');;
document.addEventListener('mousemove', function checkHover() {
 var hovered = isHover(myDiv);
 if (hovered !== checkHover.hovered) {
   console.log(hovered ? 'hovered' : 'not hovered');
   checkHover.hovered = hovered;
 }
});
```

--[pure javascript to check if something has hover (without setting on mouseover/out)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14795099/pure-javascript-to-check-if-something-has-hover-without-setting-on-mouseover-ou)

Comment: What specific tag are you wanting to target?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the listener to the document like you're doing, but in the mousemove handler, use `.closest` to see if the `target.target` or an ancestor matches a particular tag. For example, for `div`s:

```js
document.addEventListener('mousemove', ({ target }) => {
  console.log(target.closest('div') ? 'div hovered' : 'no div hovered');
});
```

```html
<div>some div</div>
<span>some span</span>
<div>some other div
  <span>some nested span in a div</span>
</div>
<ul><li>some li</li></ul>
```

You can assign to a persistent variable if you like:

```js
let hovered = false;
document.addEventListener('mousemove', ({ target }) => {
  hovered = Boolean(target.closest('div'));
  console.log(hovered ? 'div hovered' : 'no div hovered');
});
document.addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log('currently:', hovered);
});
```

```html
<div>some div</div>
<span>some span</span>
<div>some other div
  <span>some nested span in a div</span>
</div>
<ul><li>some li</li></ul>
```

You can also watch for hover over an `<input>`:

```js
let hovered = false;
document.addEventListener('mousemove', ({ target }) => {
  hovered = Boolean(target.closest('input'));
  console.log(hovered ? 'input hovered' : 'no input hovered');
});
document.addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log('currently:', hovered);
});
```

```html
<div>some div</div>
<span>some span</span>
<div>some other div
  <span>some nested span in a div</span>
</div>
<ul><li>some li</li></ul>
<input>
```

Comment: so then how would putting a variable inside work? ex:  `ishovered ` is set to 1 when div is hovered and opposite for when  `ishovered` is set to 0.

Comment: I'm not entirely familiar with this sorry if my questions sound a bit stupid.

Comment: Ideally, you wouldn't use a persistent variable at all - instead, you'd put all the functionality from a hover inside the listener. If hovered, run code A (whatever it is), else run code B

Comment: Well, I think need to set a variable to something because I have the goal of making something that works like: If body clicked: if hovering over input do nothing; if not hovering over input create a new input.

Comment: Ok, then use `=` to assign to a variable

Comment: I do have an issue, this somewhat works but if the input is selected, it will say that no input is being hovered.

Comment: Works fine here, see snippet

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/speciamone/tj7fhub4/ <-- here is my mess. You don't have to go onto it I'll probably find the problem at some point.

Comment: YES, I found the problem (I let the hovered value be set inside of a function that looped itself so I moved it out). Thank you so much!